Identification and souce of this mantra about sati in this Bengali movie 'Antarjali Jatra' (The voyage beyond)?
Mantra chanting timestamped
About Film: Antarjali Jatra, based on a story by Kamal Kumar Majumdar, is set in 1832, just after sati was abolished in Bengal, later adapted into a critically acclaimed film titled the same by Gautam Ghose. The plot centres around a sati. When an elderly Kulin Brahmin is carried to the riverfront right before his death and the priest asks him to marry a girl on his deathbed to be directly sent to heaven. He is swiftly married off to a young girl named Yashobati at the burning ghat itself, so that the girl's father, a destitute Kulin himself, would be free of the 'guilt', of failing to marry his daughter off to a Kulin groom without a dowry. He assures the pandits that when her husband dies, his daughter will commit sati.
The chant seems to go like this: .... पतिव्रता संप्रदीप्तं प्रविवेश हुताशनम् ...


Partial answer; I found the sources of the two śloka-s at the start.
Hārīta Smṛti:

ārtārte mudite hṛṣṭā proṣite malinā kṛśā ।
mṛte mriyeta yā patyau sā strī jñeyā pativratā ॥

"A woman should be known as a pativratā if she is pained when her husband is pained, rejoices when he's happy, becomes wretched and emaciated when he's gone abroad, and dies when he dies."
Mahābhārata Śāntiparva 144.9-10:

pativratā saṃpradīptaṃ praviveśa hutāśanam।
tataścitrāṅgadadharaṃ bhartāraṃ sā'nvapadyata॥

"The pativratā entered the blazing fire. There she followed her husband, who wore colorful arm-bracelets."

